# How to change language dynamically in oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

i'M Working in oracle forms 6i and i have two text field one field will write English on it and other will write Arabic i want language to change to Arabic automatically if user stand on Arabic text field and change to English if user stand on English text field

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use SET_ITEM_PROPERTY to gain the desired functionality. Pseudo-code below with an example of what I mean. Replace "TEXT_BLOCK.ARABIC / ENGLISH" with the DATA_BLOCK.ITEM information as needed.

```
if :stand_on.arabic = 'Y' then
    SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('TEXT_BLOCK.ARABIC',DISPLAYED,PROPERTY_TRUE);
    SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('TEXT_BLOCK.ENGLISH',DISPLAYED,PROPERTY_FALSE);
elsif :stand_on.english = 'Y' then
    SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('TEXT_BLOCK.ARABIC',DISPLAYED,PROPERTY_FALSE);
    SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('TEXT_BLOCK.ENGLISH',DISPLAYED,PROPERTY_TRUE);
else
    SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('TEXT_BLOCK.ARABIC',DISPLAYED,PROPERTY_FALSE);
    SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('TEXT_BLOCK.ENGLISH',DISPLAYED,PROPERTY_FALSE);
end if;
```

Comment: what :stand_on.arabic and :stand_on.english refere to ??

Comment: You said in your original post: _if user stand on Arabic text field and change to English if user stand on English text field_ -- use whatever :block.item is the indicator of whether the user wants English or Arabic.

Comment: i mean how  automaticaly change keyboard language depending on item reading order

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by changing the property of the item

for Arabic

```bash
Reading Order  => Right to Left
Keyboard State => Local Only
```

for English

```bash
Reading Order  => Left to Right
Keyboard State => Roman Only
```

This will not work with forms 10g and later.